# Circular Traversal of a Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

So I'm having some trouble with one of my functions. The program (in C++) plays a game, and there are so many players sitting at the table. Every time my play function is called, it should display to the console a player in the game. Every time it is called it should display the players in sequence. After it hits the last player it will start back at the beginning of the list/table.
    void CircleList::play()

```
LinkedListOfPlayersNode *p=(*pFront).pNext;
if (p->pData!=NULL)
{
    cout<<p->pData->getName()+" takes a turn\n";


    pLastPlayer = pLastPlayer->pNext;
}
else
{
    cout<<"There are no players. Please ADD a player.\n";
}

}
```

So lets say that that we add A, B, and C. When you use the PLAY command, C should take a turn, then B then A. As of right now with the above code, it will display that C Takes a Turn, however, it crashes right after that. 
So what is wrong with my code? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Try stepping through it with a debugger... one of your pointers is probably wrong.

Comment: I would advise you to use default elements instead of null elements in a list, this will be save you quite some time debugging.

Comment: check p before checking 'p->pData!=NULL'

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough code to see what's wrong.

Comment: Is `p` NULL when your program crashes?

Comment: @Code-Guru, my program crashes at the line: pLastPlayer = plastPlayer->pNext;

Comment: No, I don't think so. I mean when I look at it in the debugger, it has pData=???, pNext=???, pPrev=???. I don't really know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want that traversal to look something like this:

```
LinkedListOfPlayersNode *p = pNextPlayer ? pNextPlayer : pFront;

if (p && p->pData) // not sure why pData is also dynamic. look into that.
{
    cout<<p->pData->getName()+" takes a turn\n";
    pNextPlayer = p->pNext;
}
else
{
    cout<<"There are no players. Please ADD a player.\n";
}
```

Each time a player's turn comes up, they take it, and the next player is that player's next pointer. When your last player at the table takes a turn, p->pNext will be null, and the next invoke will reset to the head of the list.

At least thats where I *think* you're trying to get. Prime this with either `pNextPlayer` being set to `pFront` or `NULL`; makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are in C++, you are better off with a std::list than writing your own implementation.

Something's bugging me: Why are you starting your loop with "p = (*pFront).pNext" instead of starting it straight with "p = pFront"?

How are you adding your nodes to your list? You should be echo-ing "A takes a turn" before "C takes a turn".

If you are indeed adding to the front of your list (and your list is doubly-linked), you should call pPrevious instead of pNext.

Comment: I assume he's adding to the front of the list.

Comment: Yes, it adds at the front of the list. Specifically, it is supposed to add after the last person to play.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you initially define `pnext = NULL` in while creating nodes.

So according to your code;

```
if (p->pData!=NULL)
{
    cout<<p->pData->getName()+" takes a turn\n";
    pLastPlayer = pLastPlayer->pNext;
}
else
{
    cout<<"There are no players. Please ADD a player.\n";
}
```

There are 2 scenarios according to my assumptions:
 1. `p` and `pLastPlayer` are the same ... so after the list is over. `p` will be equal to `NULL`, your code will crash as it tries to de-reference `p->pData`.
 2. `p` and `pLastPlayer` are different ... So after the list `pLastPlayer` ends, the code will crash at `pLastPlayer = pLastPlayer -> pNext();` as you are probably de-referencing garbage or `NULL` value;

You need to check for NULL pointers at some point, either in `p -> pData != NULL` or `pLastPlayer = pLastPlayer -> pNext();`